# Regex for french characters fails validation based on the position of french character

Tags: regex, unicode, french

In my code I had a Password RegEx (written by someone) 
(`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[\x20-\x7E]{8,40}$/`) which was not supporting french characters. 
And I modified it a bit to support french characters. And 
`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?:.*[àâäæèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]*)(?=.*\d)[\x20-\x7E]{8,40}$/` is the new RegEx. But this one does not work as expected. The behavior changes with the position of the french character.
For example, NewàTest123! - works and NewTàest123! does not works

Any thoughts on why it fails when the position of the character changes?

Comment: Add these chars to the ASCII matching character class, see https://regex101.com/r/HzACAw/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You just miss `Æ` between `Ä` & `È`

Comment: That works. Thanks!! Any idea on why the other one that I posted was not working?

Comment: Look [at the regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/r/0J2Llf/2/debugger).

Comment: Thanks!! That helps!

Comment: You might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[\x20-\x7EàâäæèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]{8,40}$
```

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew